# Share bought products from order on buyer's Facebook wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

The company I'm currently working for wants to create a button that lets people share their order on Facebook after they've paid, but with the deprecation of the "Share" button I don't really know how to do it.

The "Like" button does not seem fit for this. Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to go about this.

---

You can use the [standard sharer](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/). This is good for one-off sharing or in cases where you don't have control or don't want to control how the share is rendered and you want Facebook to handle it.

`http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<url to share>&t=<title of content>`

It won't require you to have an app ID but you also won't get a nice control panel for your applications sharing [history/insights](http://www.facebook.com/insights/). You can query and get some information about the URL your sharing though by looking through the open graph.

I.E

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cnn.com
https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cnn.com
```

You can set the `URL` and `Title` of the content. The sharer will then look at the metadata on the webpage your sharing to determine the contents of the share. More below.

---

You can also use the [Feed dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/). Which comes with more customization options. The Feed dialog is the best option if your integrating sharing as an integral part of the application. I think at minimum you need to include the `app_id`,`redirect_uri` and `link` property. Look through the properties [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/). You will need an app ID to use this feed dialog and if your using the JS api you need to authenticate the user too. You can also invoke the dialog directly through a direct url where you don't need to pre-authenticate the user.

---

With either sharing method, you may wish to include custom open graph metatags on your webpage. This way you can influence how the Facebook scraper makes your share. You can set some default (pre-accepted by Facebook) open graph metatags on your page. Or you can create your own set now in the dashboard. In the Open Graph dashboard on Facebook you can customize how Facebook is supposed to read and interact with your metatags.

You can debug your pages open graph metatags by passing your URL through the debugger.

I.E

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.cnn.com

This will give you, for example, JSON or an HTML representation of how FB sees the page.